# Is it safe to define my own LC_ shell env variable ?

Tags: shell, posix

I want to send a local environnement variable (let's say `MY_VAR`) to a server when connecting with ssh. I then use the `SendEnv` option. But this requires the variable I send is accepted in `AcceptEnv` of the `sshd_config`.

I noticed that at, at least on Debian systems, default accepted variables are : `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`.

A trick I could use, to ensure my own var has chances to be accepted when I ssh on remote, would be to rename my `MY_VAR` to `LC_MY_VAR`.

But I wonder if there could be any side effect on my shell if I define my own `LC_` var ? If I refer to [doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html) this does not seem to be a problem since only a list of LCs are interpreted.

Does anyone knows if any trouble could occur if I define my own `LC_MY_VAR` ?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hmmm not sure. it's not really about security, i cannot believe i could make an attack with this , or default `AcceptEnv` in Debian needs to be reviewed ASAP :) 
the question here is more related to some commands/utils that would misbehave when defining specific LCs